# Multiple outputs from single menu

Tags: r, menu

Suppose I have a data frame like this:

```
Class  Sex  Score
A      M    90
A      F    90
A      F    85
A      M    85
A      M    80
A      M    70
A      F    70
A      M    60
B      F    90
B      M    90
B      M    75
B      F    70
```

and I want a single menu that selects the class and the sex and gets the average. Right now on my real data frame I'm using two menus

```
i <- menu(c("A","B"), graphics=TRUE, title="Choose class")
j <- menu(c("M","F"), graphics=TRUE, title="Choose sex")
df.1 <- df.1[df.1$Class==i, ]
df.1 <- df.1[df.1$Sex==j, ]
```

But when there are many more variables than just `Class` and `Sex` it seems annoying to click multiple menus when they could all be selected in the one window. Is this possible in `R`?

Comment: At a basic level you could generate a vector with all combinations of your Class and Sex like "A M", "A F", "B M", "B F" and display this in a menu. Otherwise, you probably have to build a gui of sorts, using e.g. package gWidgets, or tcltk (if you want more of a UI that can be used from a browser say, you could try shiny)

Answer (score 2):

This could be modified but the basic idea is to create an intersection of all of your options that show up and just use a single menu.

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection("Class  Sex  Score
A      M    90
A      F    90
A      F    85
A      M    85
A      M    80
A      M    70
A      F    70
A      M    60
B      F    90
B      M    90
B      M    75
B      F    70
"), header = TRUE)

vals <- interaction(dat$Class, dat$Sex)
opts <- as.character(unique(vals))
choice <- menu(opts, graphics = TRUE, title = "Choose Class.Sex")
dat[vals == opts[choice],]
```

and here is that idea wrapped up into a function

```
# data - dataset to subset
# cols - either character vector with names of the columns
#        or numeric vector with column numbers
# graphics - logical. Should the menu be graphical?
subsetMenu <- function(data, cols, graphics = TRUE){
    if(is.numeric(cols)){
        colnames <- colnames(data)[cols]
    }else{
        colnames <- cols
    }

    vals <- interaction(data[,cols])
    opts <- as.character(unique(vals))
    title <- paste("Choose", paste0(colnames, collapse = "."))

    choice <- menu(opts, graphics = graphics, title = title)
    data[vals == opts[choice],]
}

df1 <- subsetMenu(dat, c("Class", "Sex"), graphics = T)
df2 <- subsetMenu(dat, c("Class", "Sex"), graphics = F)
df3 <- subsetMenu(dat, 1:2)
df4 <- subsetMetu(mtcars, c("cyl", "gear"))
```

Comment: I appreciate this solution, but it gets ugly and lengthy very quickly when there are more than 3 variables or the variables are not just single characters. In my mind I have a single window containing all the menus simultaneously and independently (i.e. individual scroll bar, individual titles) but with a single OK button (!).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `data.table` instead of `data.frame` it offers you the advantage
that you can set the key to be the collection of columns that you want to offer as a menu option.

Then, when a selection is made, you simply pass in that value, and you have all of your appropriate rows selected

Here is an example, broken down:

```
libary(data.table)

# choose which columns are to be selected from
keyCols <- c("Class", "Sex")

# crate the data.table form teh data.frame
DT <- data.table(dat, key=keyCols)

# grab all combinations of the unique values of the columns
AllVals <- DT[, do.call(expand.grid, lapply(.SD, unique)), .SDcols=keyCols]

# create an options string for the menu
opts <- apply(AllVals, 1, paste, collapse=", ") 

# Menu
choice <- menu(opts, graphics = TRUE, title = "Choose Class.Sex")
```

Then, once an option has been chosen, you can index your `DT` by that choice. 
If you want to take the `mean` of `Score`, you can do it in the same step

```
# take the mean of all the selected rows
DT[AllVals[choice,],  mean(Score) ]$V1


# or just select all Rows
DT[AllVals[choice,] ]
```

---

*Note that if the option is not available, the latter will give an `NA` for `Score` while the former will give a value of `mean==0`*

```
DT[AllVals[choice,],  mean(Score) ]$V1
[1] 0

DT[AllVals[choice, ] ]
   Class Sex Score
1:     C   F    NA
```

Comment: Which package do I need to use `data.table`?

Comment: Sorry, `hugh`, I should have put that in there.  The package itself is also called `data.table`